# issue related to Max File size of Fileupload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have deployed my Website on `Windows Server 2007.` in `IIS`

I have added asp:FileUpload control

i have set `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="60000"/>` under the  `<system.web>` in my Web.Config file

but website doesn't allowed to Save the the file of maxlength as specified in `web.config` file.

how can i do this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Maarten answer which is right.

The problem is IIS 7 or greater have default allowed value of maxAllowedContentLength is 30000000 Byte, So if you try to upload a file greater then this limits it will display **Request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length Issue** error.

For a demo of this error which [this](http://frazsundal.blogspot.com/2011/02/request-filtering-module-is-configured.html) link

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use the following in the web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="60000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```